# jQuery: onClick if else statement not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an if/else statement for our navigation where when a user clicks on the link associated with the `dropdown-toggle` class a submenu pops up.

We have multiple links on our navigation with the `dropdown-toggle` class. I only need to target 1 not all of them that's why I'm using `.eq(0)`.

When the submenu appears a new class called `open` gets injected to the parent `<li>`.

For some reason I can't get this `if/else` statement to fully work. I have the first half working but not the second.

For the `else` portion I'm trying to add what would happen if the `open` class got injected and the `active-nav-tab` class gets added.

`active-nav-tab` is the class used for the state when users are on the current page. `active-nav-tab` is supposed to disappear when a user clicks on `dropdown-toggle` of the current page only and when they click outside the window of the submenu. Then when a user clicks on a navigation link with `dropdown-toggle`, the `active-nav-tab` again is supposed to appear on the current page. Hopefully that makes sense. I've been at this for like two days.

Code Below:

```
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).not('open')) {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').eq(0).removeClass('active-nav-tab');
        alert('test1');
        }
        else {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').eq(0).addClass('active-nav-tab');
        alert('test2');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<li>
<a class="link dropdown-toggle active-nav-tab" role="button">
<span class="tab-icon icon-header-language"></span>
<span class="tab-text">Region</span>
</a>
</li>

<li class="open">
<a class="link dropdown-toggle" role="button">
<span class="tab-icon icon-header-language"></span>
<span class="tab-text">Region</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="link dropdown-toggle" role="button">
<span class="tab-icon icon-header-language"></span>
<span class="tab-text">Region</span>
</a>
</li>
```

I don't know what I'm exactly missing. Any help is gladly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `not('open')` is using an invalid selector looking for an `<open></open>` element

Comment: @Phil Yes exactly! That's what I meant to use. What would be the best to write it out?

Comment: @charlietfl I did not know that. thanks for clarifying. what would be the best solution?

Comment: `hasClass()` rather than `not()` is what you want

Comment: Is the `.eq(0)` significant? Are you specifically trying to target the first `.dropdown-toggle` element rather than the one clicked?

Comment: @Phil I'm only trying to target the first `dropdown-toggle` not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest change you can make to your code to get the behavior you want is to replace

```
if ($(this).not('open')) {
```

With

```
if ($('.dropdown-toggle').eq(0).hasClass('active-nav-tab')) {
```

But without knowing your use case or how many "dropdown-toggle" elements you have it's hard to say if this would be a complete solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved my issue more or less. I'll see what QA says lol
Thank you!

```
    $('.active-nav-tab').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).parents().hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).addClass('active-nav-tab');
        alert('activated');
        }
        else {
        $(this).removeClass('active-nav-tab');
        alert('deactivated');
    }
});
```

Comment: What happened to the `eq(0)`?

Comment: @Phil i was using `eq(0)` when I was targeting the `dropdown-toggle` class. I was running into issues when I was on other pages where that the first `dropdown-toggle` class would always stay on. I switched the click function to target `active-nav-tab` and seemed to solve it. All in all I need that 'active-nav-tab' class to stay on the current page. That was a portion of your solution. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

this will process clicking on the first element with "dropdown-toggle" class

```
$('.dropdown-toggle:first').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-nav-tab");
    if ($(this).hasClass("active-nav-tab")) {
        alert ("Tab activated");
    } else {
        alert ("Tab deactivated");
    }
}
```

also jQuery function `not(selector)` should be used on enumeration of objects to filter it.